# How to escape arguments for the command line in python?

Tags: python, shell, shlex

I am writing a script that needs to call an external command using the `subprocess` module. The problem is I need to pass a file provided by the user to the command so it looks similar to this:

```py
p = subprocess.run("command arg1 arg2 {userfile}".format(userfile=f),
                   capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

I have to run the command with `shell=True` to make it work and that's why I pass the command as string instead of list.

The problem is that someone may pass a file named: `somefile && rm -rf ~`, which is a vaild file name for a weird reason (at least on windows. don't know about mac/linux), and then bad things happen.

Therefore, I need to escape the user input before passing it to the shell. I wanted to use the built in `shlex.quote` function for this, so with the above example I get: `'somefile && rm -rf ~'` and the command becomes: `command arg1 arg2 'somefile && rm -rf ~cmd'` which should work on unix systems. The problem is this escaping doesn't work on windows with the command prompt so my script fails on my windows machine.

Is there a built in or third party function/library that can escape command line arguments properly for all platforms, or at least for windows (because `shlex.quote` works on unix)?

I am developing on windows so I need this script to work on this platform and I don't thing that something like `"{userfile}"` is good enough.

Any solution for python 3 would be appreciated.

Comment: You use list, instead of string. `subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])`

Answer (score 1):

Pass a list to subprocess eg

```
p = subprocess.run(["command", "arg1", "arg2" , f],
                   capture_output=True, text=True)
```

*Update regarding windows*

Using an absolute path to the expected binary is usually the best approach, changing the command to:

```
p = subprocess.run(["C:\\path\\to\\binary.exe", "arg1", "arg2" , f],
                   capture_output=True, text=True)
```

If the absolute path is unknown then `which` can be used to find your binary (on recent versions of windows, I tested on Windows 7).

```
>>> p = subprocess.run(["which", "python"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> python_binary = p.stdout.strip().decode()  # Convert back to str
>>> python_binary
'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\python.exe'
```

Comment: I can't. The command I am using is on my `PATH` so I need to use `shell=True` and according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), it's recommended to pass a string in this case rather than a sequence

Comment: Use the absolute path eg `subprocess.run(["C:/path/to/binary", "arg1", "arg2" , f])`

Comment: But I don't want to hardcode the path. It may not be the same across different computers or platforms.

Comment: One potential solution then is to use the `where` command to find the location of your binary (`where` is available on recent versions of windows) eg `c:\>where ping` returns `C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE`